# For a ring homomorphism prove that $f(a^{-1})=[f(a)]^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

$R$ and $S$ are commutative rings and f is a ring homomorphism $f:R\rightarrow S.\ $ For $a\in R$  prove that
$$f(a^{-1})=[f(a)]^{-1}$$ 
Please tell me how can I start this proof.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the role of ideals here? Not to mention that if an ideal contains an invertible element then it has to be the whole ring. Also what are these brackets on the right side?

Comment: @freakish: the brackets are the easy part: he just means the inverse of $f(a)\in S$. I’m confused about the role of ideals as well, though.

Comment: @Clayton yes you are right.

Comment: Prove the result for all of $R$ and then conclude it applies to $J$.

Comment: OP: I think you just want any invertible element of $R$ maps to an invertible element in $S$ and satisfies: $f(a)=b\implies f(a^{-1})=b^{-1}$.

Comment: @freakish it is given like this in my book. And yes you are right $J=R$

Comment: The question as stated is weird. What is the point of the ideal $J$? (especially if $J = R$; then why mention $J$ at all?) Additionally, $a$ has to be invertible; it cannot just be any element of $R$. Maybe the question is "for $a \in R^*$, show that $f(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1}$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $f(1)=1$ (which is a standard assumption for unital ring homomorphisms), otherwise this is not true.

In that case if $a$ is invertible then $aa^{-1}=1$. And thus

$$1=f(1)=f(aa^{-1})=f(a)f(a^{-1})$$

Analogously $f(a^{-1})f(a)=1$ meaning $f(a^{-1})$ is the inverse of $f(a)$. Or in symbols $f(a)^{-1}=f(a^{-1})$.

Comment: Jus got of curiosity, doesn’t $f$ being a homomorphism imply $f(1)=1$? **Edit:** you’re right. We have to assume a nontrivial homomorphism.

Comment: @Clayton What about $f(x)=0$? You usually assume that $f(1)=1$ in ring homomorphism definition. But not always.

Comment: @Clayton Being nontrivial is not enough. See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179842/ring-homomorphism-with-phi1-r-neq1-s

Comment: Thanks! Learned something new :) I think I've only worked with textbooks that assume it in the definition (been a few years, though, so I'm kind of out of my depth, anyways).