# Question regarding the image of the unity $e$ of the ring $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I was reading Ring Homomorphism .

$\phi  : R \to R'$ is a ring homomorphism and $e ,  e'$ are the unities of $R $ and $R'$ respectively.

I understood that $\phi (e) $ may not be unity of $R'$.

I think the following statements are true.

( 1 )    $\phi (e) $ is always unity of $\phi (R) $ .

(2) If  $\phi  $  is on to then $\phi (e)  = e'$

(3) If $\phi  $ is non trivial and $R'$ is a field then $\phi (e)  = e'$.

Can someone check if there is any mistake in my understanding?

Comment: $\phi (R) $ is a ring with unity $\phi (e)$@BadamBaplan

Comment: Did you understand or not?@BadamBaplan

Comment: $\phi (R)$ is always a subring and $\phi(e)$ may not be the unity of $R'$.  Proof or the first statement is very easy and see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179842/ring-homomorphism-with-phi1-r-neq1-s?rq=1 for the scond one.@BadamBaplan

Comment: No no unity@BadamBaplan

Comment: Yes $\phi(R)$ is always a ring contained in $R$ with unit $\phi(e)$.  You seem to understand all of these things fine, so I'm not sure what you're looking for.  Usually we require 'subrings' to contain the unity of their parent rings. I was just pointing out the connection that $\phi(R)$ is a subring in that sense iff $\phi(e) = e'$

Comment: How $\phi(R)$ becomes a subring of $R$ itself?@BadamBaplan

Comment: Of course that is nonsensical and it was meant to say $R'$

Answer (score 0):

Yes your 3 statements are true and easy to prove ,I assume you can prove them .