# a multiplicative map mapping a commutative ring to a commutative ring preserves identity

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1_{R}$ and $R'$ be a commutative ring but do not assume that $R'$ has a multiplicative identity. Let f be a map mapping R to $R'$ be a nonzero map that satisfies $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y$ in $R$. Assume that $R'$ has no zero divisors. How to show that f($1_{R}$) is the multiplicative identity in $R'$?

I know how to prove it if we assume $R'$ to have a multiplicative identity, but now I don't know how to do this...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/homomorphisms-from-a-unital-ring-to-a-ring-with-no-zero-divisors-preserve-unity?rq=1, though it's about homomorphisms not multiplicative maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f:R \to R'$ needn't be surjective:

For brevity of notation, set

$f(1_R) = e \in R'; \tag 1$

note we have

$e \ne 0, \tag 2$

lest for every $r \in R$

$f(r) = f(r 1_R) = f(r) f(1_R) = f(r) e = 0, \tag 3$

which contradicts the hypothesis that $f$ is nonzero.   We also have

$e^2 = (f(1_R))^2 = f(1_R^2) = f(1_R) = e;  \tag 4$

thus for any $r' \in R'$ we have

$er' = e^2r', \tag 5$

or

$e(r' - er') = er' - e^2r' = 0; \tag 6$

since $R'$ has no zero divisors we conclude from (2) and (6) that

$r' = er', \; \forall r' \in R', \tag 7$

so $e$ is the unit of $R'$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I like your answer more since it is fully correct and detailed.

Comment: You are more than welcome.  Nice question.  Great user name!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to add a surjectivity condition. Indeed if $f:R\to R'$ is surjective, then for any $x\in R'$ we may find $r$ with $f(r)=x$. Then $$f(1_R)x=f(1_R)f(r)=f(1_Rr)=f(r)=x.$$

Actually it works in general, as can be seen in a linked comment (so long as the map is not identically zero). The key is to note that $f(1_R)s=f(1_R)^2s$ for any $s$ in $R'$, and then apply the cancellation law.

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, then the requirement that $R'$ has no zero divisors may be dropped. Regarding your edit: Exactly, I was about to mention that. So something must be wrong in user8734617s example.

Comment: Currently this answer is wrong since it has missed the condition that the codomain has no zero divisors.

Comment: The condition that $R'$ has no zero divisors is exactly why the cancellation law holds @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Right, and with that condition the first line of your answer is wrong.